# Using prepositions and conjunctions in a sentence

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

Which one of the following example sentences are correct/more appropriate?

1. *It is better to laugh than cry.*
2. *It is better to laugh than to cry.*

Some general tips would be helpful.

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/118144/300).

Comment: They are the same: the preposition *to* is simply elided in the first case.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. 
Meanwhile, I came across a similar question below

http://www.englishforums.com/English/ItBetterRather/gpbmg/post.htm

Sorry if external links are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways of saying it are correct. However, no. 2 is more appropriate, i think.

Comment: Agreed. #2 uses infinitive phrases for each and so it is parallel.

Answer (score -1):

No 2 sounds better. There's no grammatical rule that I know of.

As our Italian teacher sometimes used to tell us, "Suona meglio!" It simply sounds better!

Comment: That would be a reasonable comment but isn't much of an answer.  The question asks for useful tips or guidelines.

Comment: There aren't any; sometimes it's simply a matter of usage.